# Visualize Leaflet map only when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

i need an help for a javascript project. I've started studying html and javascript one month ago because i want to create a program which can be very usefull for my hobby.
I want to create a code able to create a page with a button (in this case the page is empty, but in future it will contain a database table) and, in case this button is clicked, make a map appear in the page.
I've created a script which always shows the map (without the button functionality) and it perfectly works, but as soon as I've inserted the button functionality I'm not able to solve the code errors.
Can you help me in create a script like this?
These are the scripts I've created (but they return errors); the code is composed by an html script, a ccs script and a javascript one.

This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Appearing Map</title>

      <!-- LEAFLET -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" 
  integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
  crossorigin=""/>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
  integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
  crossorigin=""></script>
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <!-- SERVE PER VISUALIZZARE I BOTTONI-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="btn btn-success BTN_1"> Mostra mappa </div>
  </div>

  <script src="mappa-demo.js"></script>

  <div class=" container Screen Screen_Data  "  >   </div>
 
  <div class="Screen Template_Mappa" style="display:none;"  >
    <div id="container">
      <!-- MAP -->
      <div id="mapid" >
    </div>
  </div>
    

</body>
</html>
```

This html script calls the style.css script:

```
#mapid{
    height: 95vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and it calls mappa-demo.js script too:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([36.849998, 14.766667], 3);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/outdoors-v9',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZ2lvdmFubmFtb250aSIsImEiOiJja2NxMWR3dWoxMGlnMzNsZnY3andkb2ZwIn0.jEysB4u6XZgrYKZrOLNBCw'
}).addTo(mymap);

$(document).ready(function()
{       
    console.log("POINT 4: CI PASSA SOLO ALL'INIZIO");

    $(document).on('click', '.BTN_1', function(event) 
    {   
        console.log("PASSATO DA BOTTONE 1: CI PASSA OGNI VOTLA CLICCO BOTTONE 1");
                
        var GetTemplateData = $('.Template_Mappa').html();
        
        $('.Screen_Data').html(GetTemplateData);
        $('.Screen_Data').show();
     });
});
```

Thank!

P.S.
After the first comment, I've updated the code, no errors are shown in the console but I can't load the map correctly. Here an image of the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The div that contains the map needs to be added before your script. Also you were missing a `</div>`.

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Appearing Map</title>

    <!-- LEAFLET -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
        crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
        crossorigin=""></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- SERVE PER VISUALIZZARE I BOTTONI-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="btn btn-success BTN_1"> Mostra mappa </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Screen Template_Mappa" style="display:none;">
        <div id="container">
            <!-- MAP -->
            <div id="mapid">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="mappa-demo.js"></script>

    <div class=" container Screen Screen_Data  "> </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Copy paste mistake? You have 2x `</body>` closing tags and an extra div in between. Also OP's cloning function will probably not be enough in the case of Leaflet: while it will copy the dynamically created content, it will miss all the event handlers and associated JavaScript objects.

Comment: @ghybs Yes it was a copy paste mistake, thank you! OP said he can't solve the errors after adding the button functionality. With this code, map shows correctly and no errors are thrown. I'm not really a Leaflet expert, but I hope this code at least solves the problems he is facing!

Comment: @VasilisS thank for your answer! I've solved one of the problem, but after having updated the code I still can't load the map correctly. I've inserted at the end of the post (I can't upload it in the comment) an image of the error. Have you have an idea of how solve the problem?

Comment: @ghybs thank you too. I've inserted at the end of the post  an image of the error (also after your comments I'm not able to load the map correctly). In your comment you talked about event handler and associated JavaScript object. Are these problems related to the error reported in the image?

Comment: @CarloMarelli No problem man. I assume the size of the map is the problem?